# Appropriate tag for questions about stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently ran into a StackOverflowError and, searching through the tagged questions on the site, I noticed that a number of them (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466597/re-using-ideas-or-small-pieces-of-code-from-stackoverflow-com) were tags simply about the site. I wanted to re-tag them with something different but I can't see any appropriate tags - can you suggest some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any appropriate tags because it's not really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.  I've migrated it here to Meta.

Comment: Looks like you're taking care of the rest too...thanks!

Comment: @Ina Yeah, that tag really needs to be watched closely.  It's a totally legitimate tag, but naming the site "Stack Overflow" gave it a dual meaning.